# spring boot application not starting on configured port number in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running sample spring boot application in spring tool suite tool.
After configuring the port I am unable to start application from browser. I am getting 404 Not found error.
Spring boot is running properly on tomcat.

application.properties

hello.greeting= nice to see you

server.port=9874

Could some one please help me to correct the problem.

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}


package demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    HelloProperties props;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam String name) {
        return props.getGreeting()+name;
    }

}

package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("hello")
public class HelloProperties {
    private String greeting = "Welcome ";

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }
}

2018-07-22 17:17:32.798  INFO 11824 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-07-22 17:17:32.952  INFO 11824 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-07-22 17:17:33.000  INFO 11824 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9874 (http) with context path ''
2018-07-22 17:17:33.006  INFO 11824 --- [           main] demo.HelloBootApplication                : Started HelloBootApplication in 2.083 seconds (JVM running for 2.862)
```

This is spring boot application, getting 404 Not Found on below link
http://localhost:9874/

Comment: without seeing the code how can i give solution to your problem? Please provide the code that causes problem

Comment: try it with http://localhost:9874/hello

Comment: You specified only "/hello" context path, so you need to request it http://localhost:9874/hello instead of just http://localhost:9874/

Comment: I had tried that too, still 404 error is getting http://localhost:9874/hello                                                                 Server is running without any errors

Comment: I am thinking, whether I had missed any other configurations.

Comment: I didn't understand why someone degraded my question, sorry for your time. It will be appreciated if you give the reason, because I can use it next time.

Answer (score 2):

Your url is wrong . You have to call the url with RequestParam name.

use this url http://localhost:9874/hello?name=test

Comment: on netstat -an command [ TCP    [::]:9874              [::]:0                 LISTENING], I am seeing like this, whether my porting is using by any other service?

Comment: I have followed this article, but I am unable to figure out what is the problem.                                                           https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/18/spring-boot-support-in-spring-tool-suite-3-6-4